# In OpenOffice Writer, how to populate a column of a table with a sequential increase in dates?

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, openoffice-writer

I am using OpenOffice Writer. In it I have a table for a time sheet. The first column is for the dates which begin from eg. 01/01/2014 and should end in eg. 20/07/2014. These dates are not already included in the table. Is there a way of populating the column with the dates in the specified range without needing manual entry?

Answer (score 0):

This involves another app, not just Writer, so not sure if it counts. Bring up OpenOffice Calc, enter your first date in cell A1. Drag the autofill handle (bold box on bottom right corner of the cell) down and it will fill in the dates in the cells below as far as you'd like. Then you can copy them and paste back into the table in Writer.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and haven't found a solution for the "native" Writer tables. So I would say, ATM it isn't possible. However, you can simply insert an OLE Object of type spreadsheet (menu Insert > Object > OLE Object) and have the full functionality of Calc available, including "Fill Down" (Edit menu or little handle at the bottom right cell corner).